# html - Vertical space between divs with no pointer event

Tags: html, css

I have a small webpage, where the background is a youtube video. There is some content on the page and I want a space somewhere, where I can click on the video to start it.
I wanted to create a div with the height of the video, but as I have seen the `pointer-events: none` only works, when the div position is set to absolute. But I have some other divs after this, so it's not really a good way.

```
__________
|Content  |
|_________|

<<space>>

__________
|Content  |
|_________|
```

Is there a way to create some space between two divs and able to click through?
I tried it also with margins, but of course nothing, because I can't "see" the video.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The video is in an iframe which is in a fixed div at position top 0, left 0, z-index -99. The page comes after this, which is above the video at z-index 0. The page contains static divs. I want to create a space between two divs (with another div or anything) where only the video is shown, and able to click it to start it.

Comment: You mean you want to click through the space or `<div>`s? from your description it seems you want to click through space… i didn't get it...

Comment: You have two DIV's floating on top of a youtube video.. right? you want to be able to click the video? what is the current behavior? why can't you "see" the video?

Comment: I will edit my question to answer both to you.

Comment: Where is the code for elements positioned at `z-index: -1` through `-99`?